# Printing to command line stops working after some time

Tags: python, loops, printing, console

I have a general question: Usually when I do python scrips, I have some logs printed to console with the `print()` command. While I run my script in Visual Studio Code it works as intendend. However, if I run my script in command line or Windows PowerShell, at random times it suddenly stops printing. I can make it continue sometimes by hitting the `Enter` key. Its not just the printing, it looks like the whole script stopped working and by `Enter` it continues. As this happened with alot of different scripts, I wanted to ask if there is something general I am missing or why it may stop working. Thanks

Comment: yeah, it's a common issue in windows os.

Comment: It's a part of the copy and paste functionality. See https://superuser.com/questions/1442941/windows-10-console-stops-running-if-i-click-in-the-console-window

Comment: Might be better to redirect standard output to a file then review its contents later

Answer (score 0):

It seems python stops printing while the user is interacting with console. To resume printing give the control back to script by clicking escape button on the console.